# Rails Access attributes after a failed save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I access the attributes of a model after a failed save and before it is rendered to the view? I want to change them back since they were modified at the model

Comment: Resetting the instance variable solved it. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the object's attributes to their original values using the following:

```
product.changes.each {|key,value| product.send("#{key}=", value.first)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to probably reload from database:

```
product.reload
```

That will pull whatever's been saved previously and discard any unsaved changes.

If you want to snapshot a model before an operation:

```
before_attributes = product.attributes

# ... Stuff that goes horribly wrong

product.attributes = before_attributes
```

That will restore any basic properties to their the previous state.

Comment: Perhaps the question was not clear. The instance is not saved in the db, it failed due to validations in the model. But the model also modifies some attributes before they are saved

Comment: The only point you can roll-back to is the last point at which the model was saved. If it wasn't saved, you have nothing to fall-back to unless you go out of your way to capture the model and preserve it at this point. I've added an alternate method to try.

Comment: Resetting the attributes of the instance at the controller solved my problem. Thanks a lot though